# YII2 Session saving multiple record on one request

Tags: yii2

i'm trying to use Dbsession to track user' activity and i got everything set and running according to yii documentation, but when a user load a page multiple session record was saved in the database in one request. image below shows the data in the database what is the cause of this and any solution to fix this?
In my config file i have this

```
'session' => [
        // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
        //'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
        'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession',
        'writeCallback' => function ($session) {
            return [
               'user_id' => \Yii::$app->user->id,
               'ip' => \Yii::$app->clientip->get_ip_address(),
           ];
        },

    ],
```

[image]

Comment: Hi,
what version of Yii2 are you using?

Comment: First column (`id`) is primary key and should be unique. You have probably messed something with table schema - you should not be able to save 3 records with the same ID.

Comment: @rob006 thanks  i think the id is not declared unique i will make changes to the schema

Comment: `id` is marked as PK in migration: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/e6c4640c9874248ff3ab694c6137e3a60c429e72/framework/web/migrations/m160313_153426_session_init.php#L42

Comment: @rob006 adding unique fixed the problem please add the comment as answer i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First column (`id`) is primary key and should be unique (it is declared in this way in [migration](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/e6c4640c9874248ff3ab694c6137e3a60c429e72/framework/web/migrations/m160313_153426_session_init.php#L42)). You have probably messed something with table schema - you should not be able to save 3 records with the same ID. `DbSession` is using [`upsert()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-command#upsert()-detail) and relies on uniqueness of `id` column.

Make sure that `id` column is primary key, or at least have UNIQUE constraint.